# Delete words from file

Tags: c#, file

I have a file like this:

```
   Tony 33, true, Opel, 1, LA, USA, Amer
   Tom  24, false, n/a, 0, Munchen, Ger, EU
   Alex 20, true, VW, 2, London, Eng, EU
```

When I read the file and I find n/a in a line I want to double the line and delete n/a from line. The output will be something like this:

```
   Tony 33, true, Opel, 1, LA, USA, Amer
   Tom  24, false, 0, Munchen, Ger, EU
   //Tom  24, false, n/a, 0, Munchen, Ger, EU
   Alex 20, true, VW, 2, London, Eng, EU
```

**Tried**

```
   while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) 
      {
         if (line.Contains("n/a")) { Console.WriteLine("found"); } 
      }
```

Any tips on how I can do this?

Comment: what u have tried so far ??

Comment: I tried to find the line which contains the word n/a, I can found it but then I don't have any ideas

Comment: while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains("n/a"))
                {                    
                    Console.WriteLine("found");
                }
            }

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is, but this looks like it might be a CSV file, if it is, completely removing a field will offset the fields of that record.

Comment: @Smeegs my goal was described, When I read the file and I find n/a in a line I want to double the line and delete n/a from line. The output will be something like this:

Comment: @MateiZaharie, I know what you're trying to do, I'm asking WHY you're trying to do it.

Comment: @MateiZaharie - The code you provided in a comment (you should edit your question to include this) is along the right lines and will "delete it", you need to be putting them lines somewhere to save back to the file

Comment: @Smeegs I need this to use in a project, it saves some info's about persons and if there is a n/a field i need to delete it but first comment that line.

Comment: @MateiZaharie, the point I'm trying to make is if the file is being read in anywhere else, it may be expecting 8 fields for each person, but if you completely remove a field, then it will only read 7 fields.  Shifting a few fields, which may break what ever system is using these files.

Comment: It doesn't, there are only info's about a person. The file is generated by some application and I have to search for 'fields' that are not attributed, double that line (for back-up) and then delete the n/a. That's it.

Comment: So, the file is never to be read? By anything?  Ever?  Why update it at all?  Wait...is this homework?

Comment: Is not hmk, of course...the file is read after by another app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I  can  suggest in your case is to take a look at [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var allLines = File.ReadLines("file.txt");
       List<string> list =  new List<string>();
        foreach (var line in allLines)
        {

            if (line.Contains("n/a"))
            {
                var newLine = line.Replace(",n/a,", string.Empty); 
                list.Add(newLine);
                 list.Add(line.PadLeft(line.Length+2,'/'));
            }
            else
            {
                list.Add(line);
            }

        }
        File.WriteAllLines("newFile.txt",list);
    }
}
```